# Akka streams - emit materialized value

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

When creating a graph using a builder we can easily emit a message once the stream has been materialized:

```
builder.materializedValue.map(actor => UserJoined(actor))
```

How can I achieve the same effect when creating a flow without graph API?

```
val source = Source.actorRef[Message](5, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
val initMessage = srcActor.mapMaterializedValue(a => PlayerJoined(a))
```

how can I make initMessage be emitted merged with source and passed to some sink without graph dsl api?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the question. Could you please elaborate, with example, what behavior you're trying to encode?

Comment: I agree with @ViktorKlang, I don't understand what you ultimately want...